# C++ standard library algorithms that require default constructibility

Tags: c++, stl, generic-programming, default-constructor, regular-type

The book Elements of Programming by Alexander Stepanov emphasizes the use of "regular types". These types have various requirements, but one of those requirements is that the type is default constructible. Alexander Stepanov is the designer of the Standard Template Library (STL), and thus has been influential in the design of C++. My question has two related parts:

1) Do any of the examples in the book Elements of Programming rely on default constructibility?

2) Do any popular implementations of the C++ standard library require any of the parameters to any algorithms to be default constructible?

Note: This question obviously excludes `uninitialized_default_construct` and related functions.

Comment: Any "popular implementation of the C++ standard library" cannot impose any additional requirements beyond the ones specified by the C++ standard. Otherwise, it fails to meet the requirement to be called a "C++ standard library".

Comment: Yes, but they are allowed to accept broader types. For instance, even though all iterator types that are at least `ForwardIterator` must be default constructible according to the standard, no standard library implementation I know of default constructs an iterator when you call `reverse`.